# How to switch writing direction from right to left in Mac apps?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, text, text-input

### Writing in right-to-left languages on Mac apps

I need to write in a **right-to-left** language, on my Mac computer. On my Windows computer, I used to press <kbd>Control (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift (⇧)</kbd> to switch the writing direction. I learned that there is a similar shortcut on Mac: <kbd>Control (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow (←)</kbd>. I also tried <kbd>Control (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>Option (⌥)</kbd> + <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow (←)</kbd>, but neither of them works in most apps except for Microsoft Word, Apple Pages.

Is there a way to switch the writing direction from right to left in Mac apps that do not support these shortcuts? I checked the Format menu in some apps, but I did not find any option for writing directions.

I often write in Hebrew, a right-to-left language. However, I've encountered an issue where the keyboard shortcut for right-to-left typing isn’t functioning in most applications, even though it is displayed in the settings when I add the RTL language.

Below is a screenshot illustrating this issue:
[image: Issue Screenshot]

Here’s another screenshot showing the menu settings and hotkeys designated for changing text direction:
[image: Text Direction Hotkeys Menu]

Apple's [documentation](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mh21243/mac#:%7E:text=Change%20selected%20text%20to%20right,Control%2DCommand%2DRight%20Arrow.) of those hotkeys:
[https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mh21243/mac#:~:text=Change%20selected%20text%20to%20right,Control%2DCommand%2DRight%20Arrow.](https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mh21243/mac#:%7E:text=Change%20selected%20text%20to%20right,Control%2DCommand%2DRight%20Arrow.)

#### Additional context:

I can make a list for applications that is problematic.

I found some workarounds: to write in right-to-left languages, I use a sticky note app that supports this feature. I edit my text there and copy-paste it to the desired app or website. However, this is not as smooth as Windows, where I can press Ctrl + Right Shift to change the text direction anywhere.

Comment: Please provide a list of Apple apps where it doesn’t work. 3rd party apps that don’t work right need to be fixed by their authors, and web page text field behavior may be a problem with their code instead of the browser

Comment: Raycast snippets for example...

Comment: That's not an Apple app.  Contact the people who make it about why it doesn't work right.  Can you name any Apple apps?

Comment: In Windows, all applications supported Right To Left input, especially websites on Chrome or Edge.

So I wondered if it was an OS-specific problem.

Comment: If would be a MacOS problem if there are Apple apps which display it.  But 3rd party app makers (including browsers) sometimes have to update their stuff in make it work right with the now annual MacOS updates.  They have advanced access to these updates to help them do that if needed.